# How can I apply padding values dynamically based on the value from the CSS class?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a parent class called "depth-0" and it contains dynamically "depth-1" and "depth-2" what I want is to dynamically capture that number and multiply with the padding-left

```css
.depth-1 {
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.depth-2 {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.depth-3 {
  padding-left: 45px;
}

.depth-4 {
  padding-left: 60px;
}

.depth-5 {
  padding-left: 75px;
}

.depth-6 {
  padding-left: 90px;
}

.depth-7 {
  padding-left: 105px;
}

.depth-8 {
  padding-left: 120px;
}

.depth-9 {
  padding-left: 135px;
}

.depth-10 {
  padding-left: 150px;
}
```

I want

```css
.depth-n {
    padding-left: calc (n * 15px)
}
```

where "n" is any number.

Comment: Not possible with CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the way around to achieve what you're looking for, like this:

```css
div{
    padding-left: calc(15px * var(--depth));
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div style="--depth:1">a</div>
<div style="--depth:2">a</div>
<div style="--depth:3">a</div>
<div style="--depth:4">a</div>
```

Alternatively, you can also achieve this using **jQuery**:

```js
$("[class^=depth-]").each(function(){
   $(this).css('padding-left',($(this).attr('class').match(/(?:^|\s)depth-(\d+)(?:$|\s)/)[1]*15) + "px");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="depth-0">0</div>
<div class="depth-1">a</div>
<div class="depth-2">b</div>
<div class="depth-3">c</div>
<div class="depth-4">d</div>
```

Alternatively, **Using Plain Javascript:**

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[class^=depth-]').forEach(function(el) {
  el.style.paddingLeft = (el.className.match(/(?:^|\s)depth-(\d+)(?:$|\s)/)[1] * 15) + "px";
})
```

```html
<div class="depth-0">0</div>
<div class="depth-1">a</div>
<div class="depth-2">b</div>
<div class="depth-3">c</div>
<div class="depth-4">d</div>
```

Comment: I like the function you did with jquery, but can you do it with vanilla javascript?
I'm using a framework where I do not have access to div classes

Comment: I just updated one more with plain Javascript, hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

you can use the variable in CSS or use Javascript.

`data-depth` is ***n***

for example:

```js
let data_depth = document.querySelectorAll('.depth');
let data;
[...data_depth].forEach((element) => {
  data = element.getAttribute('data-depth');
  element.setAttribute("style",`padding-left: calc(${data} * 15px) `);
});
```

```html
<div data-depth="2" class="depth">add depth to data-depth</div>
<span data-depth="3" class="depth">add depth to data-depth</div>
<p data-depth="4" class="depth">add depth to data-depth</div>
<pre data-depth="5" class="depth">add depth to data-depth</div>
```